# ClassNotFoundException Issue with Spring DI Demo

Tags: spring

I'm not able to run the program.

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld] for bean with name 'hello' defined in class path resource [beans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bean definition must point to the class not the package name

```
<bean id="hello" class="com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld.MainApp">
    <property name="message" value="Hello Man"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I am beginner in Springs and I found this answer helpful

Answer (score 0):

your Spring Beans Configuration is perfect but you have to give correct path for ApplicationContext in MainApp class according to your code your path should be **"main/resource/beans.xml"** . Hope this will work...